# Angular app in development mode loads JS/CSS relative to current path

Tags: angular, angular-router

Whilst *ng serve* is running and reloading the app on changes, the app tries to load resources *(*.bundle.js)* relative to the current path.

Of course, this generates a host of 404s if the current path is not the root of the app.

The `<base href="/">` element is the only thing I know of that determines the base URL. **Is that correct?**

It strikes me as odd that this would be default behaviour, but from my research I can't find much. I can get around the problem by reloading to root in the browser and navigating through to where I was before. At the moment that isn't a problem, but later, as I develop more and more levels deep this will become really annoying.

What can I do to resolve this?

Here's a screenshot of my console.

[image: Screenshot of my console.]

Here's my *index.html*:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App name</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's the *view source* of *index.html*:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App name</title>
    <base href="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

I run my project by simply running:

```
ng serve
```

Here's my *.angular-cli.json*:

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "app-name"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: <base href="/"> is what you need. Did you remove it from index.html? If so, why?

Comment: Nope. I've not touched it.

Comment: Then it should resolve the relative URLs from the root. Can you show us the generated index.html (i.e. what you get when you run your application, right-click in the broser page, and select "view page source")?

Comment: Also, can you show how do you run your project (ng serve ....)?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, simply *ng serve*.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I've added it.

Comment: Your `<base href="/">` is being transformed during the build to `<base href="">`. You've probably set an option to do that in your .angular-cli.json.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't see anything obvious in there. I've added the contents to the question.

Comment: Maybe it's in your ~/.angular-cli.json (i.e. the one in your home directory). Anyway, try adding `"baseHref": "/"` in your app properties (as a sibling of the root, outDir, assets, etc.)

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, that works. I also tried `ng serve --base-href /` but obviously your solution is better. I would think this param in the JSON should be there as standard. Also, I don't have a ~/.angular-cli.json.

Comment: I don't have it in my .angular-cli.json, and it uses / as the default. I have no idea why it doesn't in your project. Maybe you're using a buggy version of angular cli?

Comment: I've reinstalled angular-cli and all my project's dependencies and this has fixed the issue. I no longer need that extra option.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) I have fixed my problem.

First, I added `"baseHref: "/"` to my project's *.angular-cli.json* file. This fixed the issue.

However, as he mentioned, I shouldn't have to do this.

So I reinstalled Angular CLI on a global and project level, following the steps here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli. Now, the issue is resolved without having to add that option to the *.angular-cli.json* file.

I now understand things a little better.